# How do I export modal data from the program OpenModal

Tags: python, open-source

### I am asking this question for Moritz:

I managed to run the programme (ubuntu-linux-tested branch) and upload a .uff-file. When I perform the analysis it also works decently but how do I extract the modal parameters (eigen frequencies, damping and mode shape). When I click on export and select the analysis results it saves an almost empty .uff-file (see .txt file)

### Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Currently modal vectors are not yet exported in uff you would have to
open saved *.mdd file with python (mdd file is actually pickled data).
Within data you will find geometry data, modal vectors, etc.

Here is the python code to do this (see also: https://github.com/openmodal/OpenModal/issues/31):

```
import OpenModal as OM # In order to reload modules to new location when unpickling files
import pickle
import sys
import pandas as pd

sys.modules['openModal'] = OM  # In order to reload modules to new location when unpickling files
## see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398462/unpickling-python-objects-with-a-changed-module-path

file_name=r'beam_accel.mdd'
f = open(file_name, 'rb')
data = pickle.load(f)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
data[0].tables['analysis_index'].astype(str).to_excel(writer, 'index')
data[0].tables['analysis_values'].astype(str).to_excel(writer, 'values')
writer.save()
```