# Unpickling python objects from a different module

Tags: python, pickle

I have a (really) big module, that saves some objects as pickle files. I am writing a new, smaller module with some functionalities in common, that should be able to open the pickle files produced by the big module.
One file is a scikit-learn model and it works flawless. The second one is an object issued of my own class, which inherits from sklearn.base. I can actually simply copy-paste this class in my new module, it has no dependencies in the big module.

The second file cannot be unpickled because it searches for the original module and is, of course, unable to find it:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BigModule'
```

If I open the file, I can see in plain text on top:

```
BigModule.submoduleA.submoduleB.submoduleC.submoduleD
MyClass
```

As suggested here ([Unpickling python objects with a changed module path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398462/unpickling-python-objects-with-a-changed-module-path)),
I tried to replace the first line in the pickle file with several variations of:

```
smallModule.utils.mypythonfile
MyClass
```

However, this breaks something in the pickle file, because I get the error:

```
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\xe2'.
```

How can I convince the pickle module to read this file? Unfortunately, I cannot import the big module nor add anything to PATH, because the small one should work independently.

**Update**
Just to clarify, what puzzles me is that the first pickled file is stored with

```
pickle.dump(self._classifier, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

where `self` is an object of `BigModule` that does not exist in `smallModule`. However, I can open it easily in `smallModule`. In the pickle file, it only mentions sklearn on top and there is no trace of the class of `BigModule`. Why is it so? Can I change something in my other class so that only that level of reference is stored?

**Solution**

The second pickle file can be opened if the corresponding class is put in a file that follows the (empty) hierarchy of `BigModule`, taking care of the imports across submodules. For me, it only worked by putting this directory at the first level of the project.

Here is my working tree:

```
smallModule/
├── BigModule
│   ├── __init__.py 
│   └── processing
│       ├── stuff
│       │   ├── script.py
│       │   ├── __init__.py   
│       ├── __init__.py
¦   
├── data/
├── main.py
└── utils
    ├── new_script.py
    ├── __init__.py
```

The file is loaded in new_script.py and the class is declared in script.py. At the top of new_script, I add

```
from BigModule.processing.stuff.script import MyClass
```

and in main.py: `import BigModule`. Thanks to @Axeltherabbit for the idea.

Comment: if you don't have access to BigModule, can you create a mock one with fake methods? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: So, a module A pickles a file, and you create a different module B to unpickle it ? You have access to B code + B pickled files, but don't want to use nor import B. So, you need a well-defined storage/serialization contract (ideally independent from pickle), which will require code modifications in both A and B ... Maybe there is some cryptic python hack to avoid that, but I won't put a single buck on it. Last option : import A, unpickle A-type files, convert the objects into to your new B model and pickle this one => tadaaa B-style pickled files !

Comment: Pickle files *don't store class definitions* - if they worked that way, it would be impossible to ever update the class, or fix bugs in it.  Perhaps the class definition should have been moved out of `BigModule` into a smaller file, that you could reasonably distribute along with the pickle file - but that does you no good with the existing pickle.

Comment: What I don't understand is that the first model (sklearn object) is an attribute of a MyModel object. So basically I do 
```pickle.dump(self._classifier)``` and it works, although the class Mymodel does not exist in my new module. However, when I dump the object build by me it does not work, although the class exists in my code. Why is that so?

Comment: @Axeltherabbit it was a big mess with the imports because both smallModule and BigModule have a lot of subdirectories, but it finally worked! Thanks!